# c++ unit test/mock framework integrated into visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, googletest, googlemock

I want to use unit tests in VS 2012 in c++. VS allows to write unit tests, run them and see the output in test explorer window. Unfortunately it seems that VS lacks a mock framework. Do You know how to integrate for example Google Test/Mock framework into VS, so that I can still see the test results in test explorer window?

Comment: 6 years later, this is still an issue. Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384423/2118271